# Django admin actions - Override actions not found

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I need your help guys, i have some models:

```
class VerificableAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(VerificableAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        op = Operador.get_by_user(request)
        if not op is None:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

class CallcenterAdmin(VerificableAdmin):

    list_display    = ['id']
    search_fields   = ['ani']
    actions         = ['baja']

    def baja(self, request, queryset):
        print "hola"
    baja.short_description = 'Baja'

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(VerificableAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser and request.user.groups.filter(name='Personal').count() and 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CallcenterAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser and request.user.groups.filter(name='Personal').count():
            qs = qs.filter(ani=request.GET.get('q'))
            if qs.count() and qs[0].accion == 'baja':
                self.actions = None
```

So, when a user (admin and some user in group "Personal") is interacting on the view, i can't view the action_checkbox ...

I don't know what's the problem.

The idea is to have available the action "baja" only for admin users or users in personal group and qs.count > 1.

Comment: I think the first if condition in the queryset method is incorrect. Please revisit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def custom_fn(self, request, queryset):
    """Function Description it acts as action name so please add this""
created_actions = [your custom functions to be listed in django action drop down]

def create_action(self, name):
    call_action = name.__name__
    if name in self.created_actions:
        name = name.__doc__
        def call_function(self, request, queryset):
            if call_action == "custom_fn": self.custom_fn(request, queryset)
            
    return (name, (call_function, name, name))
def get_actions(self, request):
    return dict(self.create_action(x) for x in self.created_actions)
```

Comment: Here function doc string acts as a action name,and you have the place the function name in created_actions list.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).